# Accessing the AST when using Frama-C

Tags: frama-c

I want to access the Abstract Syntax Tree (AST) created by the Frama-C tool. Is there a plug-in or any other support to access the AST in Frama-C?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can follow the development gui of Frama-C

http://frama-c.com/download/plugin-development-guide-Fluorine-20130601.pdf